# Need Responsive Audio Player for all Mobile (Android, iPhone)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, responsive-design

I am developing one responsive mobile website, in that We have the functionality to run the audio file. My need it, I want the `source/name` of the music player that will run on all the browsers in Android, browser of iPad and mobile browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

I have used [html5media](http://api.html5media.info/1.1.6/html5media.min.js):

```
<audio preload="auto" controls autoplay crossorigin="anonymous">
    <source src='ABC/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "abc") %>'>
</audio>
```

But it's not working on the Firefox and Safari...

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it doesn't work on FireFox and Safari it's because you don't have a media player plugin for those specific browser. Works perfectly on my firefox, default browser and dolphin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) worked like a charm for me . And note that you can use mp4 and it should show in all browsers. For old browsers it displays it in flash

Comment: original browser on Galaxy S1 doesn't support flash

Comment: one solution can be uploading the video to youtube and setting it as unlisted thus creating a fallback for old mobile browsers

Comment: Just tried and youtube don't work on my S1 it ask to download app which i can't with company phone.

Comment: If you just use the plugin, when you open the app in the native mobile browser does it render anything or it just asks for flash?

Comment: it doesn't use the app. i don't have the app. it use normal webpage as on normal PC. I just have a big black square saying to install plugin.

Comment: Couldn't you just tell you're phone to open the video via the web ?